Socket io trigger an event twice in react js
im facing an issue. my socket io trigger twice on client side. i dont know what is the issue here.
here is my socket configure code in src/socket.ts file

and the socket connection in the mainlayout file


What exactly triggers twice? Could you provide logs of that? Also, I'm wondering if this could be related to having StrictMode enabled?

see i set data on redux store and showing an notification. the popup notification render twice.

I see, did you check what I mentioned about React's StrictMode?
If you have it enabled, it will trigger the useEffect callback twice
EDIT: You can actually make a quick test calling socket.removeAllListeners(); in your cleanup function at line 31
